# Swift 3 URLSession with URLCredential not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am doing a URLSession, but the URL requires credentials.

I have this whole method here that is trying to do a URLSession with URLCredentials:

```
func loginUser(_ username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void)
    {
        //Create request URL as String

        let requestString = String(format:"%@", webservice) as String

        //Covert URL request string to URL

        guard let url = URL(string: requestString) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }

        //Convert URL to URLRequest

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        print(urlRequest)

        //Add the username and password to URLCredential

        credential = URLCredential(user:username, password:password, persistence: .forSession)

        //Setup the URLSessionConfiguration

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        //Setup the URLSession

        let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        //Prepare the task to get data.

        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                if(error == nil)
                {
                    completion(true)
                }
                else
                {
                    completion(false)
                }

            })

        })

        //Run the task to get data.

        task.resume()

    }
```

and here are my URLSessionDelegate Methods:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0
        {
            completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
        else
        {
            completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
        }

    }

    /**
     Requests credentials from the delegate in response to an authentication request from the remote server.
     */

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential,credential)

    }
```

I notice when I debug this in this delegate method:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0
        {
            completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
        else
        {
            completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
        }

    }
```

That this method gets called twice and when it hits this line for the second time:

```
completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
```

I get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and then my app crashes! How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the crash is due to `challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust` being nil when you attempt to force unwrap it.

you should unwrap `serverTrust` and handle it being nil. my guess is that when `serverTrust` is nil `challenge.error` has a value.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
        completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
    } else if let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust {
        completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust))
    } else {
        print("unknown state. error: \(challenge.error)")
        // do something w/ completionHandler here
    }
}
```

Comment: The app does not crash anymore, but when I try to run the login method no matter was creds I put in (right or wrong) it goes directly to this line `print("unknown state. error: \(challenge.error)")`

Comment: After debugging, it will goto this line `completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust))` but then somehow run this method again and then goto this line: `print("unknown state. error: \(challenge.error)")`

Comment: are you sure there isn't a typo in the print statement? `\(challenge.error)` should be replaced by the actual error object

Answer (score 1):

Here is syntax as per swift 3.

Just verify firstly in which part of the delegate method it entered

```
open func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void){

    var disposition: URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.performDefaultHandling

    var credential:URLCredential?

    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
        credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)

        if (credential != nil) {
            disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential
        }
        else{
            disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.performDefaultHandling
        }
    }
    else{
        disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge
    }

    if (completionHandler != nil) {
        completionHandler(disposition, credential);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two issues here...first off when I run my loginUser method it runs the urlSession method twice, the first time it goes to `disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential` then the second time it goes to `disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge`

Comment: also this line `if (completionHandler != nil) {` gives me a warning `Comparing non-optional value of type '(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void' to nil always returns true`

Comment: did you tried to print the `authenticationMethod` value for second time.

Comment: look at the implementation at https://github.com/ankitthakur/SwiftNetwork

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly refactored from the above answers, a delegate class checks the number of failures, uses default unless the challenge is of type server trust it then calls the completion with trust credential:

```
class AuthSessionDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    let authMethod = challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod

    guard challenge.previousFailureCount < 1, authMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust,
        let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust else {
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
        return
    }

    completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: trust))
}
```

}