# How to bypass HTTPS server request using swift

Tags: ios, swift, https, server, nsurlsession

I want to bypass HTTPS server request using URLSession. I have an objective c code and its working well. But when I convert this code into swift and it's not working. Please check and help me. what I do wrong in my code?

```
// Objective C Code
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}

// Swift Code 
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    if let aTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust {
        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: aTrust))
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 URLSession with URLCredential not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469529/swift-3-urlsession-with-urlcredential-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Besides being a bad idea in general (if this code ends up in a shipping app, you'll have a very serious security bug), this will also break your ability to make requests through proxies, break authentication, etc.  Please just don't do this.

You can get free certs from Let's Encrypt, so there is *never* a valid reason to use self-signed certs unless you're doing something involving custom hardware that isn't connected to the Internet, and even if you are, disabling validation is still not even remotely the right way to do it.

Just delete the code and install a free cert.

Comment: How I can use certificate for send request to server?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to use a **client** cert to authenticate to the server?  Take a look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335827/client-certificate-and-nsurlsession